# Adding new rule by using QgsRuleBasedRenderer to existing one in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, rule-based

I want to add new rules for a layer. However when I add them previous one(s) are deleted. Here is my code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)

# get the root rule
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

# create clone of the default rule
rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()

# set the label, expression and color
rule.setLabel("Akarsu Kutlesi")
rule.setFilterExpression(""""Subbasin" IN (2,4,6)""")
rule.symbol().setColor(QColor("orange"))

# append the rule to the list of rules
root_rule.appendtChild(rule)
# apply the renderer
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Here is existing rules of layer:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Your code works fine. When you want to add a new rule, **do not** repeat the first 3 lines of code as this creates a new symbol renderer. Just start from

```
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
...
```

And create your new rule.

---

I find it easier to use a function like the following:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)

def rule_based_style(layer, symbol, renderer, label, expression, color):
    root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color))
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)
    layer.setRenderer(renderer)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Then you can apply new rules:

```
rule_based_style(layer, symbol, renderer, 'Akarsu Kutlesi', ' \"Subbasin\" IN (2,4,6) ', 'orange')
rule_based_style(layer, symbol, renderer, 'Something else', ' \"Subbasin\" IN (3,5,7) ', 'red')
```

[image: Example]

Comment: thanks for reply but I try that now and realize that previous rules are deleted. Here is the steps before code and after code respectively: https://imgur.com/a/pewupoO

Comment: @MustafaUçar - You are running it as a script which means every time it is run, you are creating new instances which replace everything else. The code posted should be used in the **Python Console** as you can define the parameters of the function.

Comment: I have already tried that in python console and got that result.

Comment: @MustafaUçar - Apologies but I can't replicate your problem. It works fine for me :)

Comment: Okey but can you try for me that: create a polygon shape with label - manually from QGIS- that I upload the link (first image). Then open again the project and give new rules. Previous rules are deleted (second image).

Comment: Awesome stuff, any idea how to remove the 'no filter' empty entry?

Comment: @Leo - You should probably ask this [as a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and hopefully others can suggest a method.