# Rule-based symbology based on given table

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I would like to ask if it's somehow possible to create script with rule-based symbology in QGIS which would be based on expressions given from separate table (for example CSV, or Excel sheet). I used code given from user eurojam:

```py
def rule_based_style(layer, symbol, label, expression, color):
    root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color))
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

layer = iface.activeLayer() 
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
f1 = open("d:/test.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
count = 1
for line in f1.readlines():
   rule_based_style(layer, symbol, str(count), line, "red")
   count = count + 1

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Problem is that my expression which is for example: `"Benzinka" = 'ano' AND "typ_silnic" = 'trunk' AND "Corine" = '121'` now gets another quotation marks and the result is: `"""Benzinka"" = 'ano' AND ""typ_silnic"" = 'trunk' AND ""Corine"" = '121'"`

Comment: it would be good to provide an example of your table structure and content

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Each row is one expression which is relate to my dataset.

for example one row:
"Benzinka" = 'ano' AND "typ_silnic" = 'trunk' AND "Corine" = '121'

Comment: So, you would your rules read like "row1 @excel", "row2 @excel" etc?

Comment: Yeah! I am totaly beginner to using own script in QGIS, I just work with Processing Modeller.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I edited it, could someone please reopened it?

Answer (score 3):

A basic script like the one below would do the job (based on the solution posted here [Adding new rule by using QgsRuleBasedRenderer to existing one in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282335/adding-new-rule-by-using-qgsrulebasedrenderer-to-existing-one-in-pyqgis)). The csv file in the example below is d:/test.csv:

```
def rule_based_style(layer, symbol, label, expression, color):
    root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color))
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

layer = iface.activeLayer() 
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
f1 = open("d:/test.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
count = 1
for line in f1.readlines():
   rule_based_style(layer, symbol, str(count), line, "red")
   count = count + 1

layer.setRenderer(renderer)
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: It works, but problem is, that each rule has added quotation marks there:

"""Benzinka"" = 'ano' AND ""typ_silnic"" = 'trunk' AND ""Corine"" = '121'"

Comment: in my testdata it worked...the data was like: "fclass"  =   'farm'
"fclass"  =   'town'
"fclass"  =   'town'  and  "population" > 10000