# Update rule-based symbology QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, rule-based

**Goal**: be able to update ruled based symbology

**Data** (layer attribute table): a column with the ID of the individual, a column with the date of identification (Year-month), a column with the name of the origin of this individual, and of course the coordinates.

I made a rule-based symbology in order to be able to check/uncheck the features easily by month, and by origin -> this allows me to check for example a month that interests me and select only the individuals from such or such origin. (as you can see in this example:)

[image]

**Problem**: It works very well but the problem is that I have new data every week with new months and new origins and I don't know how to update this symbology without having to start over each time. It is easy to update categorized symbology for example but I couldn't find a solution for the rule-based category.

Does anyone know a way to easily update the rule-based category?

Comment: Have you tried copying an existing rule and adapting it to the new data?

Comment: Can you detail how you create this rule-based style manually? A way to update it might be to find out how to programmatically define it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on multiple posts like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226642/automatic-pyqgis-categorized-renderer-classification) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282335/adding-new-rule-by-using-qgsrulebasedrenderer-to-existing-one-in-pyqgis), here's a way to automate rule-based symbology creation, making sure it handes all unique values from two property fields from a given Vector layer (Date and Origin in your case).

This works from the Python console on the active layer:

- It creates an empty Rule based renderer.
- Selects all Origins as possible categories in a CategoryRenderer
- Goes through all available Dates, adds a rule for data matching a given date and [refines](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRuleBasedRenderer.html#qgis.core.QgsRuleBasedRenderer.refineRuleCategories) the rule with the above mentioned categories

I tested this code (with other field names) and it works. Some extra python code might be needed if your dates are not already in a YYYY-MM format. Also, for each date, all categories will be listed not only the ones that belond to that date range. This can be improved as well by reworking the script

```py
from random import randrange
layer = iface.activeLayer()

symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
rb_renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
root_rule = rb_renderer.rootRule()

rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()


dateindex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("date_field")
unique_values_date = layer.uniqueValues(dateindex)


originindex = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("origin")
unique_values_origin = layer.uniqueValues(originindex)

categories = []
for unique_value in unique_values_origin:
    # initialize the default symbol for this geometry type
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())

    # configure a symbol layer
    layer_style = {}
    layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (randrange(0, 256), randrange(0, 256), randrange(0, 256))
    layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
    symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(layer_style)

    # replace default symbol layer with the configured one
    if symbol_layer is not None:
        symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)

    # create renderer object
    category = QgsRendererCategory(unique_value, symbol, str(unique_value))
    # entry for the list of category items
    categories.append(category)

# create renderer object
renderercat = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('origin', categories)
print(renderercat)
dates = []
for unique_date in unique_values_date:
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(str(unique_date))
    rule.setFilterExpression(f""""date_field"='{unique_date}'""")
    QgsRuleBasedRenderer.refineRuleCategories(rule,renderercat)
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

print(root_rule)
#QgsRuleBasedRenderer.refineRuleCategories(root_rule,renderercat)
print(rb_renderer)
# assign the created renderer to the layer
if rb_renderer is not None:
    layer.setRenderer(rb_renderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

With this sample data:
[image]

here's what you get after running the script:

[image]