# Automatically update category styling in QGIS when adding/deleting features

Tags: qgis, style, categorized-renderer

I have a layer where each feature represents a route, and I want these routes to be automatically categorized based on their unique IDs. In other words, if I have two routes, I should have two categories, and when I add a third route, it should automatically be assigned its own category.

Furthermore, when a route is deleted, its corresponding category should also be removed. Essentially, the number of categories should always correspond to the number of routes/features in the layer. I have managed to categorize these features manually, but this doesn't update automatically when I add or remove features.

I understand that this might involve some sort of scripting, possibly with PyQGIS. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to look at this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445269/update-rule-based-symbology-qgis/445391#445391